# Suppress red lines in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am getting some red lines (most probably the log) while I am running Eclipse program.
Can anyone tell how can I suppress them. I tried to Google it but could not find the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default if a program writes to stdout using `System.out.*` methods the output is black in Eclipse. For stderr (`System.err.*`) Eclipse uses red. Are you saying you don't want to see stuff printed to stderr? I'm not sure this would be a wise idea...

The settings for the console btw are controlled by Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console.